# package sun.awt.shell is not visible in java 17

Tags: shell, awt, java-17, sun

We migrating from java 8 to java 17, in our code we're using **sun.awt.shell** package. But while compiling i'm getting the below error,

**package sun.awt.shell is not visible
[ERROR]   (package sun.awt.shell is declared in module java.desktop, which does not export it)**

I tried command line args like below,
**--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED**, this works in java 11 not in 17.

Still getting the same issue.

Is there any replacement package for sun.awt.shell in java 17?

Comment: [The same as for the other package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78113072/package-com-sun-java-swing-plaf-windows-is-not-visible-in-java-17#comment137710462_78113072). Don’t post a new question for every package you’re not supposed to access.