# package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows is not visible in java 17

Tags: java, windows, swing, java-17

We migrating from java 8 to java 17, in our code we're using `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows` package. While compiling, I get the below error:

> package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows is not visible
> [ERROR]   (package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows is declared in module java.desktop, which does not export it)

Comment: I tried command line args like below,
**--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED**, this works in java 11 not in 17.

Still getting the same issue.

Is there any replacement package for com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows in java 17?

Comment: These `com.sun.java.swing` packages were never intended to be used outside of Java itself, and shouldn't have been used *directly*. Java now enforces that. Exactly what were you using it for? Maybe there is an alternative way to do the same thing without explicitly referencing the classes from that package. In other words, post a [mre].

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search)? If you did, then did you find this: [package com.sun.tools.javac.code is not visible in JDK17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550233/package-com-sun-tools-javac-code-is-not-visible-in-jdk17) And if you found it, does it **not** answer your question?